# Indexes Arangodb Slow query

Tags: performance, indexing, insert, arangodb

I'm usong the lastest version of arangodb 3.1.25 . 
I'm trying to insert fields but it is taking forever .
I thought of creating indexes, with running

```
db.col1.ensureIndex({ type: "hash", fields: [ "Entry" ] })
```

Yet I'm getting an error saying

```
Query: syntax error, unexpected identifier near 'db.Protein_H.ensureIndex({ type:...' at position 1:1 (while parsing)
```

What is wrong ? 
Why is it taking so many time to load ? 
how do I fix this ?

thank you

Comment: In the error message, it says something about `db.Protein_H` - where does that come from? It is not contained in the command you posted.